# When a browser is parsing a JavaScript file, does it block the main thread?

Tags: javascript, parsing, browser

Simple question.

**When a browser is parsing a JavaScript file, does it block the main thread?**

I mean, is the browser responsive during that time? Is it possible to scroll or does it get stuck?

I've thought of this question after reading the article below:

**From:** https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/javascript-startup-optimization#parsecompile

---

[image]

Comment: Modern browsers parse JavaScript *incredibly* quickly, so it generally doesn't matter.

Comment: @Pointy , thanks! But what about this image I've added from Google Developers, website? An iphone 8 takes 4 seconds to parse CNN's JS files? Is CNN loading several megabytes of JS?

Comment: If you're planning on creating a horribly bloated monstrosity like cnn.com then yes, it's probably something to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing JS does not block the "main thread", at least that's the behaviour you can observe on modern browsers. The page however is loaded from top to bottom, so if there is JavaScript inbetween, that JS will get downloaded and parsed before the rest gets evaluated.

```
 Already shown
 <script>while(true);</script>
 Not shown.
```

Therefore it is best practice to either mark your `<script>`s as deferred or async, or move them to the bottom of the page.

CNN is probably doing that too. The point is in the details:

> is **fully** interactable

As websites nowadays pretty much depend on JS for interactivity, you can't do much without it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

According to the [Chrome for Developers Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/performance/bootup-time/):

> JavaScript gets parsed and compiled on the main thread. When the main thread is busy, the page can't respond to user input.

If you only have a small amount of Javascript, you generally shouldn't have to worry about this. But I'm already seeing a lower lighthouse score for my website with as little as 170kb of JavaScript.